# Beveling - Why won't old edges go away?

Tags: modeling, edges, bevel

I'm brand new to blender and have been trying to teach myself for the past few days, but I keep getting thrown by the simplest things. In this case:

[image: Beveled edge with old edge showing]

I've beveled this edge, but the old 90 degree edge is still there. I can manually delete all 5 pieces of it, but it's super annoying to try to grab those tiny pieces.

I'm using version 2.78 on a mac, but the same thing happens in 2.79:

[image: Original edge showing after bevel]

Would really appreciate some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Have you by any chance got _Bounds_ > _Box_ switched on in the  Properties>Object>Display panel?

Comment: hmm, no. i have the feeling it's something very obvious that i'm not experienced enough to think about, though...

Comment: Shame it's not that one.Maybe share your file, or the representative bit of it, at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: To me it looks like you have duplicate vertices, try select all and remove doubles (now called merge by distance in 2.80)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is happening, but I do know that you do not have to select EVERY edge.  If you just grab each corner edge, you can hit delete and select vertices from the drop-down.  This will result with the other edges being deleted as well.